# Multiple waypoints in Google Maps API Web Services

Tags: objective-c, google-maps

I'm using the Directions API for this. The API states the parameter waypoints should be used to pass locations or addresses through which needs to be navigated. When passing one waypoint, it works perfectly:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=38.04042392261285,-95.95928934382054&destination=38.02603529451354,-95.95908408863205&mode=walking&units=metric&sensor=true&waypoints=38.03945399159401,-95.94861607401845
```

When passing more than one waypoint, it stops working. I don't get ANY response back from the request. Note that I separated the locations with the pipe symbol (|) as stated in the API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=38.04042392261285,-95.95928934382054&destination=38.02603529451354,-95.95908408863205&mode=walking&units=metric&sensor=true&waypoints=38.03945399159401,-95.94861607401845|38.02603529451354,-95.94943709477245
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems the pipe character is not being escaped, I was using this:

```
waypointsURL = [waypointsURL stringByAppendingString:@"|"];
```

Instead, use this:

```
waypointsURL = [waypointsURL stringByAppendingString:@"%7C"];
```

Comment: this was guiding me crazy already, even the documentations don't explicitly simply put as you did https://pub.dev/documentation/google_directions_api/latest/google_directions_api/DirectionsWaypoint-class.html
Thnks @mmvie